# AHKV1: How to get a long string that consists of values tht a associative array holds?

Tags: autohotkey

```
obj                     := {}
obj.kevin               :=  {}
obj.kevin.fullname  :=  "John Smith"
obj.kevin.age           :=  50

obj.hellen              :=  {}
obj.hellen.fullname := "Hellen Smith"
obj.hellen.age          := 60

obj.tim                 :=  {}
obj.tim.fullname        := "Tim Smith"
obj.tim.age             := 30
```

Lets say I have an object like the above. I want to take the `fullname` value of every sub object and concatenate it to form a long string:

```
John SmithHellen SmithTim Smith
```

I thought I could do it with a simple `loop`:

```
Loop,% obj
        str += obj[A_Index].fullname

ConsoleX(str) ; "John SmithHellen SmithTim Smith"
```

But apparently associate arrays don't support bracket indexing `[]` like simple arrays do (`MyArray[3]`), something I was under the impression that they did. Associate arrays allow for `obj["time"]` but I am not sure what I can do with that in this case.

I  thought of using a loop to do this because I figured it is the quick and dirty way, is there an actually built in facility for doing this?

It is a very common thing to do. For example enumerate all of the values of a property a object has, and maybe join them into a string. I do this all of the time elsewhere such as PowerShell.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a simple for loop<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/For.htm)</sup>:

```
obj := { "hellen": { "age": 60, "fullname": "Hellen Smith" }
       , "kevin":  { "age": 50, "fullname": "John Smith"   }
       , "tim":    { "age": 30, "fullname": "Tim Smith"    } }


for each, person in obj
    str .= person.fullname ", "

MsgBox, % RTrim(str, ", ")
```

Also, in AHK `+` doesn't concatenate strings. It's for adding numbers.
`.` is the concatenation operator.